# How to set dynamic height of webview in Xamarin.Forms uwp?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms application, and I want to set the height of a webview dynamically as pet text in uwp platform.

Comment: You can inject javascript into the webview to return the webview height on dom loaded event and then set the height accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for your webview and then inject a javascript to calculate the content's size:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Demo.UWP
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.NavigationCompleted += Control_NavigationCompleted;
            }
        }

        private async void Control_NavigationCompleted(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            var heightString = await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
            int height;
            if (int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
            {
                Element.HeightRequest = height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your Forms page's Xaml could be like:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:CustomWebView Source="https://www.microsoft.com"/>
        <!--Other controls-->
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```